# This MySQL query doesn't seem to be working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
SELECT * FROM dislikes WHERE pid = $post AND uid = $userid AND like = 1;
```

This query doesn't work (and I don't know why). Once I execute this query using mysqli and try to find num rows, I get

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\include\like.php on line 13

Just so that you know, the table dislikes is currently empty, has 4 columns: id, pid, uid and like.

EDIT:

```
echo "SELECT * FROM dislikes WHERE pid = $post AND uid = $userid AND like = 1;";
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dislikes WHERE pid = $post AND uid = $userid AND like = 1;");
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
```

This is the php code. The echo from the first line outputs:

```
SELECT * FROM dislikes WHERE pid = 2 AND uid = 3 AND like = 1;
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: You need to add error checking to your code. If `mysqli_query()` return false, print `mysqli_error()` to see the reason.

Comment: @Barmar, I will just edit it

Comment: if it is empty how can you expect it to return something ? and like is a keyword, please avoid naming your columns as keywords

Comment: @Deepanshu, I expected it to return null instead of false

Comment: then this might be due to keyword like

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`LIKE` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) in SQL.

You have to delimit column names that conflict with SQL reserved words:

```
SELECT * FROM dislikes WHERE pid = $post AND uid = $userid AND `like` = 1;
```

But the explanation for your error is that mysqli_query() returned **false** instead of a valid query result.  You need to check the function's return value to make sure it's a resource instead of **false**.

See also [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770072#12770072)

Comment: or another alternative with bill's answer is to supply an alias on the table and use that along with the column name, eg. `FROM dislikes d WHERE d.like = 1`

Comment: @491243, good tip.  In fact, you don't even need a table alias.  `dislikes.like = 1` would work too.